# How to transfer data over USB with an iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, arduino, usb

I am trying to read serial data from an Arduino project, and I was wondering how to get the data over USB with an iPad. (iPad with a camera adapter). I do realize I would have to jailbreak the iPad, which is not a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [USB-Programming on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908451/usb-programming-on-iphone).

And, at least, you can compile [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) for iOS. I haven't succeeded to use it on non-jailbreak-ed iPad with camera adapter, but it might work on jailbreak-ed iPad.

Link IOKit headers into iOS SDK from Mac OS X.

```
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework
```

Configure libusb using [configure-iphoneos.sh](https://gist.github.com/753825), and make.

```
$ ./configure-iphoneos.sh
$ make
```

Another option, [Audio Jack modem for Iphone and Android](http://www.switch-science.com/trac/wiki/ARMS22-SOFTMODEM-HOWTO). It is able to communicate with Arduino via Audio Jack without jailbreak.

Comment: "[How to bulid iPad with Arduino + Processing.js](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kougaku-navi/20110423/1303589571)" It makes Arduino is as USB keyboard.