# Can I write device driver for iOS in C++?

Tags: c++, ios, driver

I came up with a project that requires me to write a driver for a micro-controller connected to an iPhone via the lightning port. Is it possible to write the driver at all, if I don't plan on releasing it to the App Store?

Also, my second question is: What language do I have to use? I'm pretty familiar with C++ and I'm completely new to Apple devices, so I have no idea if I need to use Swift.

Comment: Wouldn't that fall under Apples MFI program? As to your second question, no, you don't "have" to use Swift, you can use Objective C instead ;); although it does have support for c/c++, but you'll spend a lot of time writing bridging code

Comment: I would recommend https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ to get started-

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way, but I don't want to throw out 90$ for taking a look if it's right (MFI)

Comment: @MadProgrammer don't spread misinformation `IOKit` is C++. this is the framework and language you would be using to write a driver

Comment: @BradAllred Having never developed with IOKit, I wouldn't know, but thanks for the heads up

Comment: It's not possible to write drivers for iOS. The only way to access the port (and bluetooth classic) is the [ExternalAccessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory). You need MFi as a hardware developer and for the AppStore. Maybe you can find this SO question useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908451/8918119

Comment: submit it as an answer, I'll flag it as correct @MihaylA.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to write drivers for iOS. The only way to access the port (and Bluetooth classic) is the [External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory).

Some common accessory features are accessible through other frameworks like [Game ControllerFramework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller). The [WWDC2013 Designing Accessories for
iOS and OS X](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/700xcx2xuedgs1rni4qry1yumg/700/700.pdf) and [WWDC2014](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/701xx8n8ca3aq4j/701/701_designing_accessories_for_ios_and_os_x.pdf) lists some of the frameworks you can use to interact with accessories.

You need MFi as a hardware vendor and for the AppStore (you need to provide your custom protocol string/s, if any). The program provides detailed information about the iPod Accessory Protocol (iAP).

Maybe you can find this SO question useful [USB-Programming on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908451/8918119)

Comment: I have a minor nit to pick here. I believe, unless something has changed in the last few years, that if you are jailbroken you can develop `IOKit` drivers for iOS.